# Custom Back Button behaviour in Fragment, using Navigation graph

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

I am writing a game in which one fragment is loaded several times successively with an increasing number of elements on the screen, so that the difficulty increases. I do this with a Navigation graph in which the level has an action to self in which it passes new parameters each time. So far so good.

The only problem is the BackStack: If I keep the default behaviour, it goes back to the same fragment, but with some weird changes in the score numbers. If I set it to go straight back to the main menu, the user might hit the back button by mistake an end up losing their progress.

So I want to display an alert dialog prompting a decision to either resume game or go back to main menu.

I know how to create the dialog but how do I show it when back is pressed? Trying to override `onBackPressed()`, `onNavigateUp()` and `onSupportNavigateup()` each give me an "overrides nothing" message. What else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following code in the Activity to show the fragments:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction t = fm.beginTransaction();
t.replace(R.id.test, MyFragment.newInstance(), null);
t.addToBackStack(null);
t.commit();
```

You can override `onBackPressed()` in the Activity, for example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // ...
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MyActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: I use a navigation graph, so I show the fragment with an onClick(): `view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_levelSelectFragment_to_chromaticFragment)`, and load the following levels with `.setPositiveButton("Play next level!") { view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_chromaticFragment_self)}`, but I´ll try your code anyway. Once I manage to translate it to kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code in my main activity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment5)
    println(navController.currentDestination?.label)
    if(navController.currentDestination?.label.toString() == "ChromaticFragment"){
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        dialogBuilder.setMessage("What do you want to do?")

            .setNeutralButton("Resume Level") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setPositiveButton("Play next level") { _, _ ->
                FullscreenActivity.level.levelSelection(FullscreenActivity.makeLevel.nextlevelsetup)
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_chromaticFragment_self)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Exit to Main Menu") { _, _ ->
                navController.popBackStack(R.id.mainFragment, true)
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_mainFragment)
            }

        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
        alert.show()
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```